# How do you filter one `collection_select` with the result of another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following block of code. My database is setup to where each State `has_many` Counties.

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= collection_select(:location, :state, State.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= collection_select(:location, :county, County.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>
```

How can I filter the second `collection_select` based on the selection of the first `collection_select`? For example, if the use selects New Jersey for the first field, then the second field shouldn't have the option to select counties in California.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Utilities controller to handle the request
2. add this method to get counties of a state

   ```
   def county_select
     @state = State.find(params[:state_id])
     @counties_html = render_to_string :partial => 'counties_select',locals:{counties:  @state.counties}
     render :json => { :counties => @counties_html }
   end
   ```
3. Add a route to it

```
    controller :utilities do
      get "/utilities/county_select" => :county_select
    end
```

4. Create a "counties_select" partial

   ```
     = collection_select(:location, :county, counties, :id, :name)
   ```
5. add a ajax on change of the first select box

   ```
     $("body").on "change", "#state_select", ->
       $.ajax
         url: "/utilities/county_select"
         type: "GET"
         dataType: "json"
         data:
           parent_id: $(this).val()

     success: (result) ->
         $("#county_select").html result.counties
       return
   ```
6. Add id "state_select" to the first select and "county_select" to the second

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not totally understanding this :/

Comment: The ides is very simple, You need a jQuery callback to detect that the user selected a state and then send the state_id to your controller so that you can update your counties collection select with counties in this state